# Primefaces 6.1 SelectOneMenu pick itemLabel as value

Tags: primefaces, label, jsf-2.2, selectonemenu

I am using PrimeFaces 6.1 SelectOneMenu to render a editable/filtered dropdown menu with itemLabel/value as selectItems. Unfortunately, selectOneMenu pick itemLabel as value put it in my selectOneMenu value field. This is very annoying issue and maybe it is a bug.

There is my snippet code:

I am using Map to hold ID/Name pair as selectItems:

```
Map<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("Cust001","John Dow");
hm.put("Cust002","Mark Polo");
hm.put("Cust003","Noel Max");
```

then I put it in my selectOneMenu as:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectCustomerId" value="#{paymentControlBean.selectedCustomerId}" effect="fold" editable="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
   <p:ajax update="paymentListToolbar"/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{hm.entrySet()}" var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Dropdown list rendering works fine, but when I pick one from the dropdown list and then press process it. My backing bean paymentControlBean.selectedCustomerId shows up "John Dow", which means, selectOneMenu pick my itemLabel into my selectOneMenu's value field.

I tried to change the PrimeFaces element to p:selectOneListBox and keep everything no change, repeat the processing, my backing bean shows up "Cust001", which is working fine.

From this comparison I found out, there must a serious bug exists in PrimeFaces 6.1, and it is same bug existing in PrimeFaces 5.2 as well.

SelectOneMenu is very popular in dropdown list selection, especially when we have to handle key/value pairs by using Map.

If it is not a bug, what I can do or have an other work around to make it pick up right value in my selectItems?

Please advise>

Comment: This issue was added to PrimeFaces within issue tracker as well, please find: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2862

Comment: Does it work on Primefaces 5.3? We have selectOneMenues in our application too without any problems (on latest primefaces elite release, but on 5.3 everything was ok too). The diffence is that we don't a effect and they aren't editable and filterable. Have you tried to remove the filter, edit and the effect? Maybe the error is caused by one of this additional attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your reminds. I shut everything off except id and value field, re-compile, and run it again, it works fine. Since then I add editable, filter, filterMatchMode, test it again. Dead. Which means, if selectItems (itemLabel/Value pair) with editable and filter at same time, will cause selectOneMenu pick itemLabel as Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it with this PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/2870

It will be in PrimeFaces 6.2 release coming out in November 2017.